# How to minimize this distance faster with Numpy? (find shifting-index for which two signals are close to each other)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numerical-methods

Given an array `x` of length 1000,  and `y` of length 500k, we can compute **the index `k` for which `x` is the closest to "`y`-shifted by `k` indices"**:

```
mindistance = np.inf  # infinity
for k in range(len(y)-1000):
    t = np.sum(np.power(x-y[k:k+1000],2))
    if t < mindistance:
        mindistance = t
        index = k
 print index
 # x is close to y[index:index+N]
```

According to my tests, this seems to be numerically costly. **Is there a clever `numpy` way to compute it faster?**

---

Note: It seems that if I replace the length of `x` from 1000 to 100, it doesn't change much the time taken for the computation. The slowness seems to come mostly from the `for k in range(...)` loop. How to speed it up?

Comment: It seems that the length of `x` is irrelevant: you only ever use `x[:N]`.

Comment: And when `x = y`, the distance is minimized at `k = 0`.

Comment: @fuglede Thank you for your comments, I updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`np.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)  which computes not the coefficient of correlation (as one might guess), but simply the sum of products like `x[n]*y[m]` (here m is n plus some shift). Since

```
(x[n] - y[m])**2  = x[n]**2 - 2*x[n]*y[m] + y[m]**2
```

we can get the sum of squares of differences from this, by adding the sums of squares of x and of a part of y. (Actually, the sum of `x[n]**2` will not depend on the shift, since we'll always get just `np.sum(x**2)`, but I'll include it all the same.) The sum of a part of `y**2` can also be found in this way, by replacing `x` with an all-ones array of the same size, and `y` with `y**2`. 
Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3.1, 1.2, 4.2])
y = np.array([8, 5, 3, -2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 7])
diff_sq = np.sum(x**2) - 2*np.correlate(y, x) + np.correlate(y**2, np.ones_like(x))
print(diff_sq)
```

This prints `[39.89 45.29 11.69 39.49  0.09 12.89 23.09]` which are indeed the required distances from x to various parts of y. Pick the smallest with `argmin`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for pointing `small sum of diff squred => high correlation` which is right. Is it a well known trick in numerical analysis to use correlation of x and y instead of directly computing sum of diff squared of x with all the possible indices to shift y? Is there no fast way to compute the latter? (especially using numpy clever vectorized methods?)

Comment: I changed the answer to use the distance you want.

Comment: Really great answer, many thanks @user6655984! A little benchmark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51488210/1422096), I didn't expect a so great speed improvement :)

Answer (score 1):

A little benchmark in addition to user6655984's wonderful answer:

```
import numpy as np
import time

x = np.random.rand(1000)       # random array of size 1k
y = np.random.rand(100*1000)   # random array of size 100k

print "Naive method"
start = time.time()
mindistance = np.inf 
for k in range(len(y)-1000):
    t = np.sum(np.power(x-y[k:k+1000],2))
    if t < mindistance:
        mindistance = t
        index = k
print index, mindistance
print "%.2f seconds\n" % (time.time() - start)

print "Correlation method"
start = time.time()
diff_sq = np.sum(x**2) - 2*np.correlate(y, x) + np.correlate(y**2, np.ones_like(x))
i = np.argmin(diff_sq)
print i, diff_sq[i]
print "%.2f seconds\n" % (time.time() - start)
```

We get a x 145 speed improvement factor :)

> Naive method
>   60911 143.6153965841267
>   8.75 seconds
>
> Correlation method
>   60911 143.6153965841267
>   0.06 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of the SSD distance ("sum of squared difference") is the maximum of the correlation.

Correlations are known to be computed efficiently (in time N Log N instead of NM), by the famous FFT.

With N=1000 and M=500000 you can expect a speedup.

Comment: SAD is sum of absolute difference i.e. `sum(|x[n] - y[n]|)` right? Aren't you speaking about SSD (sum of *squared* difference `sum((x[n] - y[n])^2)`)? Could you add a link or a paragraph explaining why "The minimum of the SAD distance is the maximum of the correlation."?

Comment: @Basj: ooops, of course. This just stems from (a-b)²=a²+b²-2ab.

Comment: Referring to (a-b)²=a²+b²-2ab does not seem to justify this, as the sum of squares a²+b²  does not remain constant: we are taking only a part of the longer array.